# Extending a C++ array by creating new one and pointing to it

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

The title of this question might be unclear but what I'm trying to do is write a program that takes an array, say {1, 4, 7}, and turn that array into {1, 4, 7, 1, 4, 7}.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void repeatArray(double* arr, int size)
{
    double* newArr = new double[size*2];

    double* ptr = newArr;

    int counter = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            newArr[counter] = arr[i];
            counter++;
        }
    }

    arr = ptr;
}

int main()
{
    int SIZE = 3;
    double* myArray = new double[SIZE];
    for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
        myArray[i] = (i+1)*2;

    repeatArray(myArray, SIZE);

    for (int i=0; i<SIZE*2; i++)
        cout << myArray[i] << endl;

    delete[] myArray;
    myArray = nullptr;

    return 0;
}
```

The above code outputs "2, 4, 6, 6.95327e-310, 6, 6". It should be "2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 6". However, the code DOES work when SIZE is anything but 3. Any thoughts here?

Comment: Tried using a debugger?

Comment: Tried realloc()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few errors.

First you are passing your array pointer in by value, so when you change it inside the function you only change its internal copy. You need to pass it in by *reference* `&`.

Next you don't have braces `{}` round your `for` loop so it only runs one of the two statements you need it to run.

Lastly you never delete the original array so you had a memory leak.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// if you want to change the value of arr outside
// the function pass by reference &, otherwise
// you only change a copy of the pointer internal to the function
void repeatArray(double*& arr, int size)
{
    double* newArr = new double[size*2];

    // double* ptr = newArr; // this doesn't seem to do much

    int counter = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        // use braces {} otherwise the for only loops ONE statement
        // but you need to loop BOTH statements here
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            newArr[counter] = arr[i]; // statement #1
            counter++;                // statement #2
        }
    }

    delete[] arr; // otherwise you have a memory leak

    arr = newArr;
}

int main()
{
    double* myArray = new double[3];
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        myArray[i] = (i+1)*2;

    repeatArray(myArray, 3);

    for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
        cout << myArray[i] << endl;

    delete[] myArray;
    myArray = nullptr;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the pointer by reference, not pass it by value.

```
void repeatArray(double*& arr, int size)
{                     //^ Pass it by reference.
    double* newArr = new double[size * 2];

    double* ptr = newArr;

    int counter = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            newArr[counter] = arr[i];
            counter++;
        }

    }
    delete[] arr; // don't forget to release the memory you allocated
    arr = ptr;
}

int main()
{
    double* myArray = new double[3];
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        myArray[i] = (i+1)*2;

    repeatArray(myArray, 3);

    for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
        cout << myArray[i] << endl;

    delete[] myArray;
    myArray = nullptr;

    return 0;
}
```

If you pass the pointer by value, the pointer in `void repeatArray(double*& arr, int size)` is just a copy of `myArray` in `main()`, the value of `myArray` doesn't change at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double* repeatArray(double* arr, int size)
{
    double* newArr = new double[size*2];

    double* ptr = newArr;

    int counter = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            newArr[counter] = arr[i];
            counter++;
    }
   //this 'arr' just a copy of myArray in side of function
    //arr = ptr;//here, you just assign to a variable inside of function,myArray outside of function has no change.


//you should return the new pointer
return newArr;
}

int main()
{
    double* myArray = new double[3];
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        myArray[i] = (i+1)*2;

    double* newArray = repeatArray(myArray, 3);

    for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
        cout << newArray [i] << endl;

    delete[] myArray;
    myArray = nullptr;
    delete [] newArray ;
newArray = nullptr;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Might want to fix that blatant memory leak in the resize function.

Comment: Thanks for the help but this solution doesn't seem to work either. Also, the problem constraint is that the method should be void.

Comment: @Asif then you *must* pass a reference-to-pointer or a pointer-to-pointer, the former if you want to retain existing syntax. Somehow the caller has to get the new sequence address. And that standing problem constraint should be part of your *question*.